# google map kml implementation

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

This is the below code for displaying map according to kml .

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.875696, -87.624207);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 11,
  center: myLatLng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml');
ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

What i need is using the parse kml to show it on map.I will embed the kml data in string and pass to api to show it on map.

I dont want the kml to be fetched from url or from any file .I just want to embed kml in this page itself.
Is it possible to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [geoxml3 third party parser](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) has a parseKmlString method which will take a string containing KML and render it on a Google Maps API v3 map as native Google Maps API v3 objects (not a KmlLayer, so you lose the benefit of tile based rendering, that KmlLayer gives you).  Might meet your requirements (will depend on how complex your KML is).